# Redirect URI field is read-only for new mobile applications registered in the Microsoft Application Registration Portal

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-account

The default value of the redirect URI for a new mobile app registration has a default value which is not a hierarchical URL. Using this value in the [Android quick-start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-android) sample results in an invalid url exception. 
The sample and the documentation require an url formatted like "https://common/oauth2/nativeclient"

The Azure Active Directory v2.0 authentication libraries docs  recommend the use of a 3rd party authentication library for Android apps and this is the library used in the Quick-start sample.

Steps:

1. Navigate to [My Applications](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList)
2. Add a new converged app
3. Add a new platform
4. Choose Mobile App
5. See that the redirect URL field is read-only and cannot be changed from "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" to a hierarchical Url like the one required by the sample docs.
6. Update the quick-start sample file, oidc_clientconf.xml to set the value to the default value from step 5

   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
7. Compile and run the app on your Android phone. Choose Connect with Open Id and supply your credentials.
8. Enjoy the uncaught exception.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that for native apps you cannot change the redirect URI for v2.0 at this point.  Your options are to use `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`.  The latter redirect uri, while not displayed in the portal, is a completely valid, pre-configured redirect uri.

For the particular sample you're looking at, it's using a 3rd party open source library that does not support the `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` format.  For this case, the alternative Redirect URI exists to allow use of other libraries that have this restriction.

Simply stick that in your sample app (or leave it in there if you're going straight off the sample) and it should not generate this exception anymore.

===========Edit==============

This answer is no longer accurate, you can set custom redirect URIs for v2.0!